# URL rewriter with htaccess and php

Tags: php, .htaccess

I want to show this URL:

```
http://test.test/htaccess/City/msh/thr/
```

to access this:

```
htaccess.php?method=City&city=mashhad&endcity=tehran
```

I tried the code below, but it does not work:

**htaccess.php**

```
<a href="htaccess.php?method=City&city=mashhad&endcity=tehran">City</a >
<a href="htaccess.php?method=Hotel&hotel=tehran">Hotel</a >
<?php
    if(isset($_GET['method']) and $_GET['method'] == 'City')
        echo 'City';
    elseif(isset($_GET['method']) and $_GET['method'] == 'Hotel')
        echo 'Hotel';
    else
        echo 'Nothing Choose';
?>
```

**.htaccess**

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    Options +FollowSymLinks
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}.php -f  
    RewriteRule ^(.+)$ $1.php [L,QSA]   
    RewriteRule ^([^/.]+)/([^/.]+)/([^/.]+)/([^/.]+)/?$ htaccess.php?method=City&city=mashhad&endcity=tehran [L]
    RewriteRule ^([^/.]+)/([^/.]+)/([^/.]+)/?$ htaccess.php?method=Hotel&hotel=tehran [L]
</IfModule>
```

Comment: The example arguments don't match tour expected results, so you'd have to hard code the replacements or grab them from a data source

Comment: well, how should i write it ?! f you know please help me because it so important form at this time.